# AWS Route 53 DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, hosting, devops

I've deleted a route 53 hosted zone, but before I made a backup of values of all NS,SOA,A,AAAA servers. Now I'm trying to recreate that zone with the same values and it does not work. I get "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" error on my google chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It seems you can't use your old name servers, so I just recreated my hosted zone and copied the new name servers to my domain settings page (below).
[image]